# Automatic comment text in review

Tags: discussion

If you are reviewing and decide to use some of the default text, this sometimes looks a bit inappropriate...

See e.g.

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/6952/2653

Should we simply update this kind of default informations or how can we handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the automatically generated texts are functions of the stackexchange network and cannot be changed on a per-site basis. However, some sites have compiled lists with building blocks for frequently appearing situations (cf. for example on the [TeX site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks)). But I think this would be a bit overkill in the present situation of the site here, as there aren't that many posts here that require some action.